# Whatsapp no-API alternative?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, messaging, instant

I created a website that connects people together in the jewelry industry. What I would like to do is to give the ability to notify a shop owner when someone wants to contact them to ask about a product. 
E.g. a visitor sees their product, and clicks on "contact seller".

Of course I could send an email, or connect through an SMS provider. But emails are not that immediate or interactive, and SMS costs money.

Ideally I would want to send a Whatsapp on the receiving end, but they don't provide an API for that.

Is there an alternative that I can use to notify the shop that someone is interested in buying one of their products, so they can go into the website / email? I just need to alert them, on their mobile device, and I prefer not to create my own app for just that.

Comment: So you want some kind of push notifiction. You need to think on what device / os  you want the notification and go from there. It is also possible to push notifications to the client browser with signal-R

Comment: Exactly, I want a push notification, but don't want to create my own App for that. I rather connect to an existing App. Coverage for Android and iOS is good enough for me.